# How can I add a Class and Method in the template of MFC ActiveX Control

Tags: mfc, controls, activex

I want to create an ActiveX Control and I found that the MFC ActiveX Control template would be the best choice.
However, I can't add class and method in the ActiveX Control I have made. And I cannot address this class or method in other projects. Is there any document about that?
Thank you

Comment: Can you detail "I can't add class and method in the ActiveX Control I have made" ? Anyway, you can find here a sample of using ActiveX Control in MFC: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9537/Adobe-ActiveX-Control-with-MFC

Comment: I have made a new control in 32bit and then call it in an MFC App with 32bit. And it still not work. I can not add variable in it